Noise in classical quantum transmission
In classical quantum transmission, we introduced a scattering model that includes two components: free projection and collision
Now, in this figure, this model is introduced that when it goes up in the triangle, it is in free flight, but when it collides, it collides at zero time and space and starts moving again.

This figure is for one electron, now if we put, for example, 100 electrons and take the average, it will be an almost straight line with a series of oscillations.

What factors does this fluctuation depend on?
And which noise is it similar to flicker or shot or thermal and why?
Schematic 3 to noise

Ref: What Can Electric Noise Spectroscopy Tell Us on the Physics of Perovskites?


To understand noise shape, derive a frequency spectrum. Also, we don't usually talk about noise from "semiconductors" but from specific electronic devices. From your description, it could reasonably be thermal noise.

@edmz Thank you very much, now I am questioning 3 pictures from an article, I think it looks like a shot


What factors does this fluctuation depend on?

It depends on the temperature (increases how much energy atoms and electrons have) and also the construction of the device (in semiconductors you might have very small channels for the electrons to travel in or they might bump into an insulator). If there is recombination this could also affect it.

And which noise is it similar to flicker or shot or thermal and why?

The black line looks like Pink or 1/f noise, which looks like a random walk (markov process).
